# extra post fields for url + youtube video / implementation

Tags: custom-field

i'm using wordpress v3.1 and i'm requiring 2 extra fields for external url + youtube-link.
is it possible?

in case it's not - i was considering using own tags for the post-content and filter it out.

btw. what's the easiest way to implement youtube videos (via link) directly into the post?

thx

Comment: Could you elaborate? You need those 2 extra fields for each post? What do you want to do with them on the post?

Comment: i'm requiring it separately for special formatting of the post content. i will try with tags now ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/adding-meta-boxes-to-your-post-screen/
Is a post I wrote the other day about adding meta boxes.  I use it to put links in to change the link some of my post titles use.  I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for exactly, as I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'extra fields'

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)